# Populating lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a loop to populate a list, using a loop format.
I'm supposed to create a list, then - using a loop - populate the list with N elements, and set each list element to its index multiplied by 10.

It is also possible that N will be 0. In this case I'm supposed to output an empty list [], and this what I think is tripping me up.

```
list = [N]

for x in range(N):
    innerlist = []
    for y in range(N):
        innerlist.append(list)
    list.append(innerlist)
    if N == 0:
        list = []
print (list)
```

I thought that the `if(N==0)` statement would reset the value of the list but it doesn't. I should output `[]` but instead I output `[0]`.

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: please give an idea of an input and output. also, never call a variable by a class name, e.g. use `lst` for a variable name, not `list`.

Answer (score 6):

```py
>>> N = 10
>>> my_list = [iter * 10 for iter in range(N)]
>>> print(my_list)
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
>>> N = 0
>>> my_list = [iter * 10 for iter in range(N)]
>>> print(my_list)
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = range(8)
innerlst = []


for i in lst:
    if 0 in lst:
       innerlst = []
       continue
    else:
       innerlst.append(i*10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just add the condition *before* entering the whole loop, you'll get the expected result:

```
N = 10
list = []
if (N > 0):
    for i in range(N):
        list.append(i*10)
print(list)
# output: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = []

if N == 0:
  print(myList)
else:  
  for i in range(N):
    myList.append(i * 10)
  print(myList)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm coming from the reviews queue because this was flagged as low-quality. A little explanation also goes a long way with answers. Code-only answers are often outright deleted because they don't explain how they work (which is what will really help OP and incoming readers).. additionally/unfortunately this code snippet also doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming the OP is also using the same Codio environment, this snippet does in fact work. I will add comments in the future, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just a beginner myself, but I found this online that matches your question. I have no idea how to format the actual code right, but hopefully this helps!

```
my_list = []
my_newlist =[]
if N <= 0:
    print(my_list)
else:
    for x in range(N):   
        my_list.append(x)   
        my_newlist= [i* 10 for i in my_list] # not getting the statement 'i * 10 for in i' statement
    print(my_newlist)
```

[Python] #We provide you with a number N. #Create a list then, using a loop, populate - Pastebin.com. (2017, November 29). Retrieved from https://pastebin.com/2F0zXq6z

Comment: There is a {} button that formats the code that you selected.